# My Phone wont detect controller without 3rd party apps

Tags: 8.0-oreo, xiaomi, game-controllers

My phone is Xiaomi A1.

I am using [OTG type C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072V9CNTK) -> [Controller to USB adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J4JVFXI) -> [PS2 Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004YRQ9)

alot of online guide i read, i only need to plug it in.

But i need to use previous version of [USB/BT Joystick Center 2019](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.poke64738.usbjoygold&hl=en), for my phone to detect it.

The problem is this apps treating D-pad & Left Analog as same input,same as face buttons & right analog.

And it detected my USB adapter as PSX adapter.

Are there work around, or alternative apps for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** SOLUTION -> press analog button between analog sticks and it will work properly ***

--- ALSO WORKS WITH MANY MANY MANY different controllers which have mode/home/analog or some strange additional button u normally dont see on anything else ---

+++ for example Genius MaxFire Grandias 12 have mode button which by default is glowing in green and its in digital mode but after u press it it turns red and its changes to analog mode +++

That is most stupid thing i experienced with controllers and i have like 14 different ones already (for pc) and tested twice more i believe but as i see issue exists even on phones.
I was looking for something else and i found this question by accident. Solution is on top and reason why it happens is that 99% of controllers with analog sticks have 2 mods:

- Digital
- Analog

in digital mode u can have only up down left right and in most cases left stick is adapting dpad while right is adapting face buttons just for sake of giving them some functionality in that mode, but for some controllers its like analog and dpad works as dpad but face buttons loses functionality and right stick is taking it over i have no idea why but in like 90% of cases right stick works as face buttons but face buttons work properly

as for Analog mode ur both sticks have 360° of movement dpad still have up down left right and right stick becomes another 360° stick and now face buttons works just fine